# Terminator Toggle Opacity Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, terminator

Do you know any keyboard shortcut to adjust or toggle the terminal's opacity without right clicking and going into preferences? That would be so sweet if that is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terminator does not support hotkeys to change background opacity or color:

> To my mind, rewriting the config file on the fly is the wrong way to
>   achieve the things you want. A much better way would be the dbus
>   server that we've started to introduce. It is designed to allow things
>   running inside a terminal to communicate with Terminator and send
>   commands that will affect the terminal. **For now it only exposes
>   commands for splitting, but over time I hope we will be able to extend
>   this to include things like colours and transparencies, etc.**

https://answers.launchpad.net/terminator/+question/173257

---

CompizConfig allows you to change any window's opacity with a keyboard shortcut. The effect is different than Terminator background opacity, but it's good enough for me -- I want to glimpse the web page behind my terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

[image: CompizConfig Settings Manager > Opacity, Brightness and Saturation]

---

Related:

- [How do I change the transparency level of gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59907)
- Terminator does support other hotkeys and a configuration file:

  - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man5/terminator_config.5.html

Answer (score 4):

One workaround is to create multiple profiles according to the transparency levels and then switch to the required profile using the keybindings in terminator.

For example, I need to toggle transparency in terminator. So I have 2 profiles.

- default --> opaque
- transparent --> with transparency set to 0.80 (all the other settings are the same)

And I have mapped the following in terminator keybindings:

- next profile --> ctrl+0
- previous profile --> ctrl+9

This allows me to toggle opacity in terminator.

Comment: This the real answer to the question !